# SQL replace and insert Into

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table "NamesTable" in SQL Server.

```
ID      NameEnglish      NameFrench
-----------------------------------
1       Loyalty Apple     Null
2       Home Watermelon   Null
3       Company Banana    Null
```

I want to insert and replace in a second column the corresponding name like this

```
ID      NameEnglish       NameFrench 
-----------------------------------------
1       Loyalty Apple     Loyalty Pomme
2       Home Watermelon   Home Melon 
3       Company Banana    Company Banane
```

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO NamesTable (NameFrench)
VALUES ('Frenchreplace') 

SELECT 
    [ID], 
    NameEnglish AS [Frenchreplace], 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (NameEnglish, 'Apple', 'Pomme'),
                     'Watermelon', 'Melon'),
                     'Banana', 'Banane') AS [Frenchreplace] 
FROM 
    NamesTable
```

The query runs and replace the selected words, but do not insert into my existing table. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to modify your existing data you need `UPDATE` - a `SELECT` query doesn't modify data.

Comment: @DaleK please see my update thanks

Comment: My comment still holds - you need an update statement. Insert is for inserting new rows (not columns - the column exists from the first insert), update is for modifying existing rows.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Looks like you wanted to `UPDATE` the column `NameFrench` base on column `NameEnglish`. But how does `Orange` become `Watermelon`  for `ID` `2`?

Comment: @sorry yes there is no oranges here. i did edit thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what is the objective of your `INSERT` query. But you don't need that.

You need an `UPDATE` query. `SELECT` only retrieve from the table, it does not modify or make changes to the table.

Change your `SELECT` query into an `UPDATE` query

---

```
UPDATE N
SET    NameFrench  = REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE (
                                                NameEnglish, 'Apple', 'Pomme'),
                                       'Watermelon', 'Melon'),
                             'Banana', 'Banane')
FROM   NamesTable AS N
```

---